# Why are these adverbs being used?

Tags: translation, words

I was reading this section of an n2 book

この地方のスキー場はコースの大部分は整備されており、滑りにくいということはあまりありません。ただし、風が強く、**せっかく**降った雪も積もるか積もらないか**のうちに**飛ばされてしまうことが多いです。

And a few doubts came to me:

1)Why is **せっかく** being used here?

2)Why is のうちに being used ?

3)What is the meaning of this passage「**せっかく**降った雪も積もるか積もらないか**のうちに**飛ばされてしまうことが多いです。」

Can someone help me?

Comment: The third question looks like a straight-up translation request with no evidence of research effort shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. せっかく is an adverb/no-adjective that modifies some valuable chance which one failed to take advantage of. For details, please read any introductory article about it, like [this](http://maggiesensei.com/2015/04/29/how-to-use-%E3%81%9B%E3%81%A3%E3%81%8B%E3%81%8F-sekkaku/). Here a snowfall is the "chance" being missed. The sentence still makes sense without せっかく, but it adds the feeling of disappointment.
2. It's part of the [～か～ないかのうちに construction](http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=kanaikanouchini).
3. Roughly, "unfortunately, snows often end up being blown away before they start to pile up." Note that せっかく and ～か～ないかのうちに are two irrelevant grammar points.